# Having trouble with submittingAnswer to Redux in react-quiz-app

Tags: reactjs, redux

We are building a quiz with react, redux and an API. And we are having a problem with the submitAnswer dispatch in our code. We can't get the function to work. The answer itself is not passed along with the action. Since it's quite a big chunk of code I will link to the repo:

https://github.com/annaester/technigo-final-project/tree/main/frontend/src

The reducer is in the file: questions.js and the dispatch is used in Game.js

In redux dev tools the answer-array stays empty when we try to submit the answer. And the console.log gives us:

```
react-dom.development.js:4091 Uncaught TypeError: store.questionList.find is not a function
    at submitAnswer (questions.js:38:1)
    at createReducer.ts:277:1
    at produce (immerClass.ts:94:1)
    at createReducer.ts:276:1
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at reducer (createReducer.ts:243:1)
    at reducer (createSlice.ts:325:1)
    at combination (redux.js:528:1)
    at D (<anonymous>:2298:16)
    at L (<anonymous>:2314:13)
```

This is the reducer:

```js
submitAnswer: (store, action) => {
  const { questionId, answerIndex } = action.payload;
  const question = store.questionList.find((q) => q._id === questionId);

  if (!question) {
    throw new Error(
      "Could not find question! Check to make sure you are passing the question id correctly."
    );
  }

  if (question.options[answerIndex] === undefined) {
    throw new Error(
      `You passed answerIndex ${answerIndex}, but it is not in the possible answers array!`
    );
  }

  store.answers.push({
    questionId,
    answerIndex,
    question,
    answer: question.options[answerIndex],
    isCorrect: question.correctanswer === answerIndex,
  });
},
```

this is the handler in component:

```
const onAnswerSubmit = (_id, index) => {
  dispatch(
    questions.actions.submitAnswer({
      questionId: _id,
      answerIndex: index,
    })
  );
};
```

and the map of the answers:

```
<ButtonBox>
  {ques?.options?.map((answer, index) => (
    <AnswerBtn
      key={answer}
      onClick={() => onAnswerSubmit(ques._id, index)}
    >
      {answer}
    </AnswerBtn>
  ))}
</ButtonBox>
```

Comment: Hey :) I think you'd be more likely to get an answer if you provided a snippet of where you think the issue is. Which function call isn't working and what the error message is.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems were that I was comparing a string with and integer. And I was also passing information that I didn't need. So I cleaned up the code and passed it like this:

```
submitAnswer: (store, action) => {
      const { questionId, answerIndex } = action.payload;
      const makeNum = store.questionList.correctanswer;

      if (answerIndex === +makeNum) {
        console.log("correct answer!");
      } else {
        console.log("wrong!");
      }

store.answers.push({
        questionId,
        answerIndex,
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Without having access to your backend, it's a bit of guess work to be honest. But my first observation is that this line in your `submitAnswer` action looks wrong:

```js
const question = store.questions.find((q) => q._id === questionId);
```

Shouldn't `store.questions` be `store.questionList`? This is because I can't see `questions` in your `intialState` object:

```js
const initialState = {
  questionList: [],
  amountOfQuestions: 24,
  currentQuestion: 0,
  answers: [],
  steps: 20,
  quizOver: false,
  quizStart: true,
};
```

You're accessing it via a selector in `Game.js`, but the naming is wrong:

```
const ques = useSelector((store) => store.questions.questionList);
```

So I think just changing `questions` to `questionList` in your action should fix your issue:

```js
const question = store.questionList.find((q) => q._id === questionId);
```